# In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[11.0. 4]"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

In my project I was using complete play-services dependency like :-

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

But, I need only maps and location dependencies. And also need to update PlaceAutoComplete. For this I am adding latest maps, location and latest places dependencies and remove the complete play-services library. When I try to remove the play-services library I am getting this error :-

```
In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency 
depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[11.0.
4]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by 
the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4 -> 
com.google.firebase:firebase-common@[11.0.4], but fir
ebase-common version was 16.0.3.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or 
have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase- 
appindexing@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase- 
messaging@17.4.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase- 
common@16.0.3
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play- 
services@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.8
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic- 
links@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.github.ankitdubey021:GPSTracker@2.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase- 
database@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase- 
storage@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase- 
config@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database- 
connection@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase- 
analytics@16.4.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics- 
impl@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services- 
measurement-api@16.4.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase- 
crash@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services- 
appinvite@11.0.4
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@17.1.0

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with 
./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the 
google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding 
"googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
uild.gradle file.
```

These are the dependencies I am using in my project:-

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation project(path: ':calendar')
implementation project(path: ':filepicker')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

// butter knife
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.hedgehog.ratingbar:app:1.1.2'
implementation 'co.lujun:androidtagview:1.1.4'
implementation 'com.sdsmdg.harjot:materialshadows:1.2.5'
implementation 'com.h6ah4i.android.materialshadowninepatch:materialshadowninepatch:0.6.5'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
    // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp dependency module and define your own module import
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:2.0.6'
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.12'
implementation 'com.whiteelephant:monthandyearpicker:1.2.0'

//implementation 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.1.5'
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.veinhorn.scrollgalleryview:library:1.0.8'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:25.1-android'
implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.luongvo:iOS-SwitchView:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
implementation 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
implementation 'bg.devlabs.fullscreenvideoview:library:0.0.9'
implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1'
implementation 'com.github.tibolte:agendacalendarview:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.github.ravindu1024:android-viewpager-indicator:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.3@aar'
implementation 'com.whiteelephant:monthandyearpicker:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
implementation 'com.github.didikk:sticky-nestedscrollview:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'
implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.41.0'
implementation 'com.github.ankitdubey021:GPSTracker:2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong ?

Comment: I have a similar problems too. Still looking for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies on referring to different versions.

I think this is the root of your problem:

```
Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4 -> 
com.google.firebase:firebase-common@[11.0.4], but fir
ebase-common version was 16.0.3.
```

You are mixin both firebase and play-services versions somewhere:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0

com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl@11.0.4
```

I also think you are missing a couple of referred firebase libraries that needs to be added.

A lot of 'thinks', sorry for not having a straight answer.